# Discord.py - Is there a way to edit a sent slash command message from a bot?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a discord bot that gets images from dalle. I have the api set up and it will send back and image link, but I am using slash commands in discord and the request from dalle takes longer than discord allows bots to take. I am trying to find out if there is a way to edit a message, as I have resulted in sending, 'Waiting on DALLE's response...' then editing it after the DALLE image has come back. I would like it to send back the image as soon as the image url has come back. Here is my code:

```
@bot.tree.command(name="image")
@app_commands.describe(arg = "The bot will respond with DALLE's response to this query")
async def image(interaction: discord.Interaction, arg: str):
    messageToEdit = await interaction.response.send_message("Waiting for DALL E's response...")
    response = await getDALLEImage(arg)
    await messageToEdit.channel.edit_message(messageToEdit, content=response)
```

The way to edit there is just a way I tried, I can't seem to find how to edit it, and maybe it's because it's a slash command and not a normal command.

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just use `await message_to_edit.edit()`?

Comment: I'll try it but I think I already have, edit: It doesn't work

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe this helps: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/discussions/9101

Alternatively you could just send a second message after the `"Waiting for DALL E's response..."` with the image link from DALLE.

Answer (score 2):

[interaction.edit_original_response](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.Interaction.edit_original_response) serves this purpose.

```
@bot.tree.command(name="image")
@app_commands.describe(arg = "The bot will respond with DALLE's response to this query")
async def image(interaction: discord.Interaction, arg: str):
    await interaction.response.send_message("Waiting for DALL E's response...")
    response = await getDALLEImage(arg)
    await interaction.edit_original_response(content=response)
```

Alternatively, if your command takes a while to response, you can [defer](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.InteractionResponse.defer) and [followup](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.Interaction.followup), although this doesn't provide specific information on waiting i.e. "Waiting for DALL E's response" and only says "Bot is thinking".

```
@bot.tree.command(name="image")
@app_commands.describe(arg = "The bot will respond with DALLE's response to this query")
async def image(interaction: discord.Interaction, arg: str):
    await interaction.response.defer()
    response = await getDALLEImage(arg)
    await interaction.followup.send(content=response)
```